# oriented on (a subject)

Tags: prepositions

Can someone be oriented 'on' something?

For instance,

> oriented on content instead of process

or

> oriented on the long term instead of short term

Or should it always be used with 'towards' like 'oriented towards'?

Comment: Focused on, sounds better

Comment: Both prepositions *towards* & *on* can be used appropriately to the context. From what can be guessed in the example phrases, *towards* seems to be the right preposition. However, you must provide full sentences and context to let use understand the exact meaning you are trying to convey. I **can** say "oriented **on** content instead of process" in a certain context.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "oriented ***toward***" or "focused ***on***", since these are the correct prepositions in their non-metaphorical meanings.

The word "oriented" isn't completely dissociated from its non-metaphorical meaning for me, so using ***on*** evokes a mixed metaphor. If you wanted to say that you learned a lot ***about*** the game of chess, people don't say: "I dived deep ***about*** the game of chess".

Comment: That sounds right but wouldn't *getting familiar with* the subject be more appropriate? A little lost there :/

Comment: @itsols: *getting familiar with* doesn't mean the same thing as *oriented toward*, so they are appropriate in different contexts. We don't know the OP's context.